# Reload UITableView Data without repositioning UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, layout, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UITableView that receives its data from an NSFetchedResultsController. The NSFetchedResultsController's data is updated occasionally by network calls. After each time the data is updated from the network call, I update the UITableView with [tableView reloadData] in order to add any new items.

Part of my UI also enables cells to be repositioned horizontally. I would like these cells to not be re-positioned each time the table's data is refreshed, but unfortunately, [tableview reloadData] does just that.

What is the ideal way to update the data in a tableview without repositioning it's rows? Should I override the tableview's reloadData method and do something fancy there or perhaps override the tableview cells layoutSubviews method?

I position the cell like so:

```
CGRect newFrame = cell.frame;
newFrame.origin.x = -cell.frame.size.width;
cell.frame = newFrame;
```

After the NSFetched Results Controller receives more data from the network call, it calls it's delegate's method:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.eventTableView reloadData];
}
```

Which calls *tableview: cellForRowAtIndexPath:* and the cell that is returned from the dequeue has it's origin at (0,0)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EventCell";
    EventCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        [cellNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        cell = self.customCell;
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    Event *event = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell configureCellWithEvent:event];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Perhaps post some code on how this repositioning is happening because otherwise it's tough to suggest an alternative.

Comment: @Dima there isn't much code to post because most of it occurs in Apple's implementation of `[tableView reloadData]`. I move the cells by modifying their frame and when I call `[tableView reloadData]`the cell that is returned from `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]` has its origin at (0, 0).

Comment: There may be a better way to do this, but what about creating a custom view for the cell then have the cell listen for an update and update itself?

Answer (score 0):

You might try the UITableViewDelegate method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`, which is invoked just before any cell is added to the table view or scrolls into the table's visible area.  In there, you can position the cell if needed, and this will work after reloading.

This isn't essential to your question, but I'd also suggest changing the cell's transform property instead of its frame.  That way you can't accidentally move it farther than you want it to go (say if you shift it twice).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  //Determine if the cell should be shifted.
  if (cellShouldShift) {
     cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0 - cell.bounds.size.width, 0);
  } else {
     cell.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
  }
}
```

Comment: This method is called after cellForRowAtIndexPath at which point the cell is already set to it's origin. So if I know whether or not the cell had been previously moved, I could accomplish the same thing there. The difficult part is figuring out if the cell was previously moved before it was reloaded. I guess I can keep some sort of flagging property on the cell but that seems a bit hacky.

Comment: Is it feasible to insert rows (with `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`) when needed in instead of reloading the table view?  If not, you're probably going to have to resort to something hacky.

Comment: I think I'll have to resort to something hacky because the network calls also have information that updates the UI of cells that already exist. :(